# Scala Map call multiple functions

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and am a beginner. My trainer has given me some work, see below:

> Let's construct a bouquet of functions that would test the following conditions on a given no "n". A) check prime. B) check if square. C) check irrational. Construct the bouquet as a Map[Char, Int=>Boolean]. Now accept the integer and code in {A, B,C} from the command line to call the appropriate function and print the result.

I write all program A, B and C. But using Map I don't know what to do.

```
object firstProgram
{
  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit =
   {
     square(9);
     primeNumber(19);
   }
  def square(x: Int): Unit =
  {
    var no = math.sqrt(x);
    if((no%1) == 0)
      println(x +" IS A SQUARE NUMBER OF - "+no.toInt);
    else
      println(x +" IS NOT A SQUARE NUMBER");
  }

  def primeNumber(x: Int) : Unit =
  {
      var a =0;
      var returnValue = false;
      for(a <- 2 until x)
      {
          if( (x%a) ==0)
            returnValue = true;
      }
    if(returnValue == false)
      println(x + " IS A PRIME NUMBER");
    else
      println(x + " IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER");
  }
}
```

How can I understand the question, and how to do it with Map?

Comment: The idea is that you store all the checks on a **Map** so the program will receive as input the number to check and the check to do _(as a single letter)_, and you would extract the check from the map. - Anyways, I am pretty sure your trainee won't be happy that you solve this using mutability, and your checks are not checks, since they do not return a **Boolean** but instead print a value.

Comment: I don't see why there is a predicate to check if an `Int` is irrational. There's no way plain integers can be anything but rational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your map has keys that are characters and values that are predicates, I think your trainer wants you to have the letters 'A', 'B', and 'C' corresponding to `isPerfectSquare`, `isPrime`, `isIrrational`, etc. You can do that as such:

```
val checksMap = Map(
  'A' -> isPerfectSquare _,
  'B' -> isPrime _,
  'C' -> isIrrational _
)
```

Of course, for this to work, you'd have to change the signatures of your methods to look like

```
def isPerfectSquare(x: Int): Boolean
def isPrime(x: Int): Boolean
def isIrrational(x: Int): Boolean
```

Afterwards, you can read integers from the command line and iterate through the map, and if a check doesn't pass, you're probably supposed to print something like `s"Check $key didn't pass"`

```
for ((k, v) <- checksMap) if (!v(n)) println(s"Check $k not passed")
```

And may I suggest a cooler implementation of `isPrime` that I found online?

```
lazy val primes: LazyList[Int] = 3 #:: (LazyList.from(5, 2).filter(x => !primes.takeWhile(math.pow(_,2) < x).exists(x % _ == 0)))

def isPrime(x: Int): Boolean = x == 2 || primes.takeWhile(_ <= x).last == x
```

Link to Scastie (fill in the blanks): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WRw8Z6FxSauBvxQ9PChbPA